# Know of a good jQuery Date Picker (sort of) Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that will allow the user to select a range of days and hours, per week, that they are able to work.  This is for a job application form.

I do not want the user to pick specific dates, rather I would like them to see a generic week on which they could select their desired hours for each day.

Mondays - 8am to 6pm
Wednesdays - 1pm to 5pm
etc.

I have looked at https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar and I like the way it works, but it is still date specific and much more than what I need.  I didn't dig into it too much to see how difficult it would be to pull out the pieces I would need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't offer you a plugin, but I had a similiar problem where I used the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) to select time ranges. You could use seven slider that you can enable and disable, et voilà, there's your work hour plugin.

Comment: Would it not be far more simple to just have 5-7 labels and 10-14 text fields with a max length of 2?

Comment: @maenu - I was leaning toward doing something like that.  I thought this might have been a more common requirement than it seems to be.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Yes, it probably would be if there is no plugin I can grab and plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBHKz/5/) with a jQuery UI widget that uses sliders. Just to give you an idea how this would look.

Comment: Added some labels, and a click by 15 minutes (more in line with the idea of a scheduler). http://jsfiddle.net/ZBHKz/8/

Comment: Awesome!  I added in AM/PM.  What do you think would make the most sense for disabling a day if the user does not want to work that day?  Maybe a checkbox next to the slider.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZBHKz/10/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.projectcodegen.com/JQueryDateTimePicker.aspx

http://home.business.utah.edu/rohit.aggarwal/datetimepicker/

Comment: Those both appear to have the requirement of forcing the user to pick an actual date.  I want it to be a bit less specific and generalized.